# Dynamics crm 2011 - asynchronous plugin

Tags: plugins, asynchronous, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to build a plug-in for a Dynamics CRM 2011 installation.

My problem is that I don't find information related to the order in which the plug-in instances are executed. Microsoft says that the synchronous plug-ins are executed in the 'expected' order; but they say nothing about the asynchronous ones.

Is there a way to figure out the order in which the user actions where executed based on the plug-in execution order?

Answer (score 4):

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/124c9126-ef56-4be0-a712-cf71d088295f

Comment: That is the answer from another site to my question :).